# WCF uses a new instance on every call, despite InstanceContextMode.Single being set

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'd like to re-use the same host instance on every WCF call.  Everything I've read on the Internet says the exact same thing; use the `[ServiceBehavior]` attribute.  So, that's what I've done:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class DALService : IDataAccess
{
    private string _adminConnStr;

    public void ServiceStart()
    {
        _adminConnStr = ConnectionStringManager.GetAdminDatabaseConnectionString();
    }

    public IEnumerable<CustomerInfo> GetCustomerInfosOrderedByShortname()
    {
       // _adminConnStr is null here!
    }
}
```

I've set a breakpoint in `ServiceStart` to make sure that was getting run.  I've set a breakpoint in `GetCustomerInfo`, and `_adminConnStr` is once again null.  I've also set a watch on `*this` and the addresses are indeed different.

I'm wondering if this is because I create the `ServiceHost` objects programmatically, rather than using IIS which sets all that stuff up for you.  Perhaps I need to be doing something more when I create the host?  Here's my code for that:

```
var contract = attribute.ContractType;

var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(attribute.ServiceType ?? instance.GetType());
serviceHosts.Add(serviceHost);

var uri = String.IsNullOrEmpty(service.UriPrefix)
    ? new Uri(String.Format("http://{0}:{1}/{2}", serverName, port, contract.Name))
    : new Uri(String.Format("http://{0}:{1}/{2}/{3}", serverName, port, service.UriPrefix, contract.Name));

if (uris.Contains(uri))
    throw new DuplicateServiceRegistrationException(uri);

uris.Add(uri);
serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior
{
    HttpGetEnabled = true,
    HttpGetUrl = uri
});

serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(contract, new BasicHttpBinding(), uri);
serviceHost.Open();
instance.ServiceStart(); // This line will set _adminConnStr

Console.WriteLine("{0} now listening at: {1}", service, uri);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Figured it out.**

It seems that *WCF* won't set your Singleton instance until the first time you call it.  Basically after this line:

```
var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(attribute.ServiceType ?? instance.GetType());
```

`serverHost.SingletonInstance` will be `null`.  So, when I call:

```
instance.ServiceStart();
```

I'm calling `ServiceStart` on an instance that WCF doesn't know about.

So, I need to set the singleton instance on WCF when I create `serviceHost`:

```
var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(instance);
```

Then, I can call `.ServiceStart` on *that* instance.  This will fix the issue.